# Manage Qty Stock update using Magento SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap, cataloginventory

We are using below like code for Qty stock update using Magento SOAP API.

```
try {
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.magentosite/index.php/api/?wsdl', array("connection_timeout" => 5,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'exceptions' => true, 'trace' => 1));
$sessionId = $client->login('user', 'apikey');
$resultCatalogProductList = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.list');

$allPordIds=[];
foreach ($resultCatalogProductList as $prod) {
    $allPordIds[]= $prod['product_id'];
}
$allProdStockList=$client->call( $sessionId, 'product_stock.list',   array( $allPordIds));
$calls = array();
foreach ($allProdStockList as $product) { 
   $updatedQty=10;
             $calls[] =array( 'product_stock.update', array($product['sku'], array('qty' =>$updatedQty, 'is_in_stock' => $updatedQty > 0  )) ); 
}
foreach (array_chunk($calls, 100) as $skuChunk) {

            $result=$client->multiCall($sessionId, $skuChunk);
             print_r($result);

        $cnt++;
    }
```

Currently our store have 2500 products and We want to stock update of all product.For that We have used array_chunk($calls,100) so it will Break into blocks of 100 for speed boost.

So when we call above script then it will take to much time to update.and Sometimes it will continue load.

So please help us for above slow loading qty update to make faster.